# jquerymobile 1.3.X - Any latest plugins for splitview

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am looking to use a good jquerymobile plugin for splitview.

I used asyraf9's plugin (http://asyraf9.github.io/jquerymobile-splitview/) for my old version, but latest version of  jquerymobile isnt supported by the plugin.

Requirements-

- Page should look like this
  http://asyraf9.github.io/jquerymobile-splitview/
- Should show only the left content on iPhone, and show left & right on ipad
- When in iPad view, it should show only left part, and navigate from Left -> right on click of a list item.
- I can't use Panel to create splitview, as I'm already using a panel for slide menu.

Is there any exisiting plugin that I can use with JQM 1.3+ ?

Note - Similar question (asked by someone else) was marked as duplicate - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19504645/any-solutions-out-there-for-splitview-in-jquery-mobile-1-3-x . I am aware of cocepts like floating and media queries, but need a plugin that handles javascript to navigate to Right side content in iPhone.

Thanks in advance ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up writing custom code to achieve this.

When in iPad view, it issues an AJAX get request to update div on the Right.

When in iPhone, it navigates to a different page when clicking an item on the left.

```
@media all and (min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 800px) {
    .leftsidePart
    {
    clear:both;
    width:100%;
    }
    .rightsidePart
    {
    display:none;
    }
}



    @media all and (min-width:800px){
    .leftsidePart
    {
    float:left;
    width:30%;
    }
    .rightsidePart
    {
    float:right;
    width:65%;
    }
}
```